# C++: How-to sort 2-d array with qsort?

Tags: c++, 2d, quicksort, qsort

```
Example:     Result:

[9,1]        [0,5]
[5,2]        [2,4]
[6,3]        [5,2]
[2,4]        [6,3]
[0,5]        [9,1]
```

I know that the meaning lies in the comparison function. How to sort in ascending or descending order.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you only sort by the first column or do you then sort by the second column? And is this really a 2D array or an array of `std::pair`?

Comment: 2 questions: 1. What have you tried? 2. Do you really have to use `qsort`? If no, then use `std::vector` of `std::pair`s and use `std::sort` for sorting it.

Comment: If you know the meaning lies in the comparison function, what's your problem?

Comment: Sort only by the first column. I want to use QSORT, because he is the fastest. `int meow[100][100]`

Comment: "I want to use QSORT, because he is the fastest." apparently you are conflating something. or something.

Comment: He probably read it on the internet which automatically makes it true.

Comment: The details of the implementation depend on the details of the data structure it operates on. Why don't you include the type and variable declarations. Also, if you look at the example on [cppreference/qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort), you should be able to put the comparison function together yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `std::sort` from the `<algorithm>` header

you can use a lambda expression as comparison function

Comment: No. We need to use qsort. This is critically important.

Comment: @user2010633: you mean, you have an assignment that says to use `qsort`. why do you not say that outright

Comment: This is part of problem. Yes, problem says "only Qsort" but is fastest. It should be a limit on the execution time and the task involves a large amount of data. I need only syntax.

Comment: @user2010633 you should profile first in order to determine whether the hypothesis that `qsort` is faster holds. I seriously doubt it would.